# Richtextbox: Embedd image and surround with text

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I would like to embed an image in an Richtextbox in way that the image is sourrounded by text (should look like a newspaper article which contains some images).

That's what I have until now:

```
<RichTextBox>
    <Paragraph>
        <InlineUIContainer>
            <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Width="200" Height="100" />
        </InlineUIContainer>
        <Run Text="{Binding Text}" />
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBox>
```

This code embedds the image in a way so that the first line of the run starts at the bottom right edge of the image.

But I would like to embedd it such a way:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVUNz.jpg

How can this be implemented for WP7.1?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this can be done, i believe you would be looking at either Margin or Padding around the image.....As the whole thing will look like an object because that's what it is.

so you want to put Padding or Margin around the image to push the text away from the object giving the appearance of space between the object. Also try Pushing the text to the right and the image to the left.

I hope this will help a little. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done until [FlowDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163371.aspx) will be available in Silverlight. Or somebody invents a similar control.